# $values not printing in ng-repeat which avilable in map in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have map which is having key and vaule has values startes with $. And i am displaying these things in table using ng-repeate. But values which start with $ not printing in table.
I have sharing code, can some please let me know how can i achive this

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
      <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>
    <div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
    outside of map:------- {{name1}} --------printing ok
    <br> <br>

    <table >
          <tr>
           <td width="15%" class="greyTdHeads tdPad">Field Name</td>
           <td width="14%" class="greyTdHeads tdPad">Field Value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in params">
           <td class="whiteTd tdPad">{{key}}</td>
           <td ><input
             Type="text"
            ng-model="params[key]"></input></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    inside of map , not able to print
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "John Doe";
        $scope.name1 = "$top";
     $scope.params=
     {without$:"without$val","$with$":" ",$batchsize:" ",$expand:" ",$filter:" ",$orderby:" ",$select:" ",$skip:" ",$top:" "}
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can someone plz tell where can i get help for this , is there any forum where angularjs developer are more active.

Answer (score 0):

Angular ignore variables starting with '$' because he uses some variables with this standard like for example $$hashkey

it applys to angular.equals, {{}}, ng-bind

you can create a new directive and read those values but i dont recommend it

have a good day.

Comment: I know it will ignore form map. But i want to display in same way like using escape. can some one plz help